# aligning sub menu with the main menu

Tags: html, css

My `sub-menu` and `sub-sub-menu` seem to have a lot of gap from each other and is not aligned with the main menu. I want the `sub-menu` to drop down straight from the main menu and `sub-sub-menu` to open up on the right side of the `sub-menu` when hovered over. How can I do that?

below are my codes:

```css
   .nav-bar {
     max-height: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     padding-left:20px;
     padding-top: 200px;
    }
    
    .box-nav-bar ul{
     display:inline-block;
     
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin:0;
    }
    
    .box-nav-bar ul li{
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 20px;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     width: 100px;
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     
    }
    .box-nav-bar ul li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     list-style: none;
     color: black;
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-family: Arial;
     display:block;
     
    }
    .box-nav-bar ul li:hover{
     background-color: grey;
     
    }
    
    .box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu ul li{
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     width: 150px;
     
     
    }
    .box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu {
     display: none;
     font-size: 14px solid;
     position:absolute;
     text-align: center; 
    }
    .box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu{
     display: block;
     
    }
    .sub-sub-menu{
     display: none;
     font-size: 14px solid;
     position:absolute;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    .box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu li:hover{
     display: block;
     
    }
```

```html
 <div class="nav-bar">
      <nav class="box-nav-bar">
       <ul>
        <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
         <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
           <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>                      
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
             <li>
              <a href="#">Latest</a>
             </li>
             <li>
              <a href="#">Archive</a>
             </li>                      
            </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have `position: absolute` on your `.sub-menu` and `.sub-sub-menu`. You just have to align your container blocks using the `top` and `left` properties.

Also `font-size: 14px solid` is invalid as `solid` is a `border-type` attribute and not required with `font-size`. Change it simply to `font-size: 14px`.

Refer code:

```css
.nav-bar {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 91px;
  left: 0;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 140px;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu li:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="box-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dolor </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Conse </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Latest</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Archive</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get started.

```css
.nav-bar {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px solid;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !Important;
}

.sub-menu li:hover .sub-sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.sub-sub-menu {
  display: none !important;
  font-size: 14px solid;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -2px;
  left: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu li:hover {
  display: block;
}

.sub-sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="box-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Latest</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Archive</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```